# When auto filling the textbox using javascript mvc still shows required red icon

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Hi have two textboxes and a checkbox with an ok button.
When I enter name in first textbox and press ok, it shows second textbox is required.
And when I click the checkbox, it auto fills the same name from first textbox to second.
But it still shows the required red tag on second textbox.
Currently I am using jquery to fill the data into second textbox.
If I fill the second textbox manually, the red required sign goes away.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The unobtrusive validation events wont fire when you modify the value of a textbox that validation has already fired in. You'll need to execute the .validate() method on your form in the checkbox click event. Something like $(this).parents('form').validate();

Comment: You mean to say, fire this event after filling the information the second textbox?

Comment: Yes, after you've set the value of the second input box then fire the validate event on your form and that will cause the validation events to refire. I beleive you can also call .validate() on the second input box to trigger the validation on that input box only, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your first input has an ID of firstInput and your second input an ID of secondInput and your checkbox has an ID of myCheckbox you can use:

```
    $('#myCheckbox').click(function () {
         //Toggle the value of the input         
         $('#secondInput').val( $(this).is(':checked')? $('#firstInput').val(): '');

        //Fire validation ONLY on the secondInput field
        $('#secondInput').valid();

        //OR Fire validation on the entire form
        $(this).parents('form').valid();
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't `valid()` simply return a bool value where `validate()` actually reevaluates the field?

Comment: Yes, .valid() returns a boolean but it causes the validation to fire (displaying the error messages). My test form on an existing project wasn't displaying the error messages when I ran .validate(), it could be something specific to how my validtors were setup. Rather than mess with it I just used .valid() which produced the result that Alice asked for.

Comment: See the documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation, it looks to me like the .validate() method is expecting some rules to be passed and maybe that is why it isn't displaying the validation messages. Either way, .valid() does work.

Comment: One more note, it looks like this MAY do the trick when using .validate(): http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

Comment: I did try $('#divtag').validate().form(); but it didn't work.I inserted inside my jquery function which is filling the secondcheckbox.

Comment: Did you not try ".valid()"?

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
$("#myCheckbox").click(function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $("#input2").val($("#input1").val());

    $("#input1").triggerHandler("keyup"));
    //OR
    $("#input1").triggerHandler("focus"));
  }
});
```

Comment: jQuery Validate already extends the .validate() method to anything it is bound to. Calling .validate() on either the entire form or the individual input will trigger validation to occure. There is no need to attempt to fire additional events to force the validation to occure when the method is already exposed.